# Overridden method init() in MainActivity is not working after upgrading of Corodva CLI from 3.6 to 5.1.1

Tags: java, android, cordova, phonegap-cli

```
public void init() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    {
        CordovaWebView webView = new CordovaWebView(this);
        CordovaWebViewClient webViewClient;
        webViewClient = new CordovaWebViewClient(this, webView)
        {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView arg0,
                    String url) 
            {
                //Log.i("TestApp","URL:" + url);

                if(url.contains("**"))
                {
                    saveToPrefsInt(getContext(), "isCustomer", 1);
                    url = url.replace("*", "");
                }

                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(arg0, url);

            }


        };
    }
}
```

I want to save preference **isCustomer** at init and get its value in onCreate method and also want to change URL in init method.
Method was working fine in Cordova 3.6.4 but gives following error in 5.1.1:

1. Cannot instantiate the type CordovaWebView
2. CordovaWebViewClient cannot be resolved to a type

**CordovaWebViewClient** is reomved in Corodva CLI 4.0.0 is there any alternative to this.

Comment: Hm, I noticed, the cordova.apache.org site has change notes and documentation - also 6.0.0 seems to be out. Does one has to "import" the class files of the classes, that are now not possible to be instantiated, did the names change or the signatures?

Comment: I have treied with:
    
WebView wV = (WebView)appView.getEngine().getView();
But in this case appView is always NULL.